# Favicons Customization Or Animation

Tags: php, javascript, css, html

I want to customized my favicons, so this is what I want

when i go to my home page my main favicon image will be display with a home icon beside it
then i go to the contacts the home icon will be change to profile icon.

I know this is possible but I don't know how to do it could someone help me to achieve this certain output ?

If you don't understand what I really mean I would like to make youtube.com as a reference, as what you see at youtube when you play a video a play icon will be place beside there favicon icon

Help please, Thank you Cheers

Comment: The [play icon is a *browser feature*](http://thenextweb.com/google/2013/02/25/google-chrome-may-soon-get-audio-indicators-to-show-you-noisy-tabs-keep-them-open-when-memory-runs-out/) that indicates a tab is playing audio (so you can find which of your many tabs is disturbing the office). It has nothing to do with YouTube code or Favicons.

Comment: @Quentin so are you saying that this is not possible though ? :x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change it without page reloading, you can look at [favicon.js](https://github.com/Dlom/favicon.js).

[favicon.js demo](http://dlom.github.io/favicon.js/#)

Other way is setting different favicon url for each page.

At index page

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/home.ico" />
</html>
</head>
```

At profile page

```
<html>
<head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/profile.ico" />
</html>
</head>
```

Answer (score -2):

The symbols in the page title are defined in the header of the page(before you define the charset)
Here is one [ascii](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) table, you just get your code and you create your page and put the codes in the title tag.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>&#187 Viewing this post</title>
</head>
</html>
```

This will output a blank page with the title like this : » Viewing this post

Comment: That isn't what the question is asking about. The charset should be set in the HTTP headers (so before any of the HTML). If you specify the charset with a meta element, then there is no reason it should appear after the title element. Character references should be terminated with a `;` character. Abusing punctuation marks as arrows is ugly at best and has the potential to give weird results in screen readers.